# What test would be used to find out if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{n^2}/n!$ is convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Just need a hint, to figure out which test to use to start solving this problem:

> Find out if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {2^{n^2}}{n!}$ is convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

What test would I use to try and figure this problem out?

Comment: Did you try the root-criterion ?

Comment: @Peter Will try that now, but would I just leave n! as is? not sure how to approach the problem because of the factorial

Comment: Ratio test works just fine.

Comment: If factorials are present, the ratio test is usually the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Ratio test
$$\frac{2^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}=\frac{2(4^n)}{n+1}$$
so, it diverges

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test will bear fruit.  Cancellations between exponents in the numerator and denominator, and between $(n+1)!$ and $n!$, will give you a workable result.

Answer (score 0):

First, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}\ne 0$.  So, the series diverges.

Alternatively, note that $\left|\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}\right|^{1/n}\ge \frac{2^n}{n}\to \infty $ as $n\to \infty$.  The root test, therefore, guarantees that the series diverges.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark